# Loop returns correct changes when outside function, does not show changes when run inside function

Tags: function, loops, for-loop, dictionary, iteration

I'm iterating over old keys in a dict. I've tested the for loop outside of the function and achieved the desired results but when I put it into a function, it returns the old keys instead.

Been trolling the forums but come up with nothing.

```
edu_dict = {
        "A.S":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "AAS":"Attended Vocational/Technical",...etc}

def clean_edu(edu_dict):

    for i in list(edu_dict):

        key = i  # accesing the key from the edu_dic
        lower_case = key.lower() # changing the key to lower case

        char_change = "".maketrans(chars_in, chars_out)        

        clean = lower_case.translate(char_change)      

        y = re.sub(r'\s\s{1,}','',clean)

        edu_dict[y] =  edu_dict.pop(i)      

        return edu_dict

clean_edu(edu_dict)
print(edu_dict)
```

It seems like a simple solution but I'm stumped.

Comment: this seems like viable solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the dictionary, or else you will just be modifying a copy of it in the function.  The function modifies this copy, but outside the function, the original dictionary will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think u either are not passing a reference  into clean_edu or you are not saving the return value of clean_edu.  In both cases you are cleaning a copy of your dictionary instead of changing the original object as intended. Then you print the original unmodified dictionary.